# c: interpreting bytes of a given sequence as int16_t values and summing them

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to figure out how to add sequential bytes in a block of data starting at a given place(sequenceOffset) to a certain length(sequenceLength), by typcasting them to signed 16 bit integers(int16_t). The numbers can be negative and positive.I also cannot use any arrays, only pointer syntax.

```
*blockAddress points to the first byte of the memory region
*blockLength is number of bytes in the memory region
* sequenceOffset is the offset of the first byte of the sequence that
* is to be summed
* sequenceLength is the number of bytes in the sequence, and
* sequenceLength > 0
*
* Returns: the sum of the int16_t values obtained from the given sequence;
* if the sequence contains an odd number of bytes, the final byte
* is ignored; return zero if there are no bytes to sum


int16_t sumSequence16(const uint8_t* const blockAddress, uint32_t blockLength,
uint32_t sequenceOffset, uint8_t sequenceLength){

uint16_t sum = 0; 
const uint8_t* curr = blockAddress; // deref
uint16_t pointer  = *(uint16_t*)curr; // typecast to int16

 for (uint16_t i = 0; i< sequenceLength; i++){
     sum = sequenceOffset  + (pointer +i +1);
 }// for
```

an example of a test case:

--Summing sequence of 8 bytes at offset 113:

5D  5C  4E  6E  FA  B3  5D  4C

23645   28238  -19462   19549

You said the sum is: -7412

Should be:           -13566

i'm not sure how to handle the case where I ignore the final byte if the sequence contains an odd number of bytes.

Comment: The problem statement is confusing. The buffer consists of some number of 2-byte signed integers, possibly with an extra byte on the end? Is it in big-endian, little-endian, or native form? And how are we supposed to handle overflows when we sum?

Comment: Versions using the `uint16_t` expression cause undefined behaviour due to strict aliasing violation

Comment: What is `blockLength` used? To limit `sequenceOffset` and `sequenceOffset + sequenceLength`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int16_t sumSequence16sane(const uint8_t* block, uint32_t length)
{
    int16_t ret = 0;
    while (length >= 2)
    {
       ret += block[1] << 8 | block[0];
       block += 2;
       length -= 2;
    }
    return ret;
}

int16_t sumSequence16(const uint8_t* const blockAddress, uint32_t blockLength,
uint32_t sequenceOffset, uint8_t sequenceLength)
{
    return sumSequence16sane (blockAddress + sequenceOffset, sequenceLength);
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t b[8] = { 0x5d, 0x5c, 0x4e, 0x6e, 0xfa, 0xb3, 0x5d, 0x4c };
    printf("%d\n", sumSequence16sane(b, 8));
}
```

Some might prefer this inner loop. It's a bit more compact but potentially a bit more confusing:

```
    for (; length >= 2; block += 2, length -= 2)
       ret += block[1] << 8 | block[0];
```

Comment: how would I go about this using strictly pointer notation and no arrays?

Comment: @Texasy04 you can replace `a[b]` with `*(a+b)`

Comment: This would cause undefined behaviour on 16-bit int systems